# A randomised variant of the Littlewood conjecture

Tags: diophantine-approximation

A famous [conjecture of Littlewood](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Littlewood_conjecture) asserts that for each $\alpha, \beta \in \mathbb{R}$ and $\varepsilon > 0$, the set
$$ A(\alpha,\beta;\varepsilon) = \{ n \in \mathbb{N} \ : \ \Vert \alpha n \Vert \cdot \Vert \beta n \Vert < \varepsilon/n  \}$$
is infinite. (Here and elsewhere, $\Vert x\Vert = \mathrm{dist}(x,\mathbb{Z})$ denotes the distance to the nearest integer). It is known that for generic $\alpha,\beta$ a stronger statement is true. Namely, for $(\alpha,\beta) \in [0,1]^2$ chosen uniformly at random and any $\varepsilon > 0$, the set
$$ \{ n \in \mathbb{N} \ : \ \Vert \alpha n \Vert \cdot \Vert \beta n \Vert < \varepsilon/(n \log^2 n) \} $$
is almost surely infinite. (This follows from a more general result of Gallagher, see e.g. [here](https://arxiv.org/abs/1610.08007)).

I am interested in the asymptotic behaviour of the set $A(\alpha,\beta;\varepsilon)$ for generic $\alpha,\beta$. Naive heuristics (pretending that the events "$n \in A(\alpha,\beta;\varepsilon)$" are mutually independent for all $n \in \mathbb{N}$) lead to the conjecture that
$$ \# A(\alpha,\beta;\varepsilon) \cap [0,N] \sim \varepsilon \log^2 N.$$
Is the above asymptotic correct for generic $\alpha,\beta$ and small $\varepsilon > 0$? It seems like one can apply a second-moment method to get some result, but the problem quickly becomes quite technical and I don't have strong intuitions as to what one should expect.